# The binary operator LessThan is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]'

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to create and Odata endpoint but I'm getting this error whenever I try and perform any queries involving dates.

I've re-created it in a *very* simple example below.

**Database Table**

[image: Database table "Person"]

**EDMX (Snippet)**

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="DataWarehouseModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="DataWarehouseEntities1" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
      <EntitySet Name="People" EntityType="DataWarehouseModel.Person" />
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="Person">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="FirstName" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
      <Property Name="LastName" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
      <Property Name="DOB" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="3" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
<!-- C-S mapping content -->
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
    <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="DataWarehouseModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="DataWarehouseEntities1">
      <EntitySetMapping Name="People">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="DataWarehouseModel.Person">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Person">
            <ScalarProperty Name="DOB" ColumnName="DOB" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="LastName" ColumnName="LastName" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="FirstName" ColumnName="FirstName" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
    </EntityContainerMapping>
  </Mapping>
</edmx:Mappings>
```

**Model**

```
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class PersonController : ODataController
{
    private DataWarehouseServiceContext db = new DataWarehouseServiceContext();

    private bool PersonExists(int key)
    {
        return db.Persons.Any(p => p.ID == key);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return db.Persons;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**Queries**

```
http://localhost:53205/OData/Person?$top=20&$filter=DOB eq 1972-11-20T00:00:00.000Z
http://localhost:53205/OData/Person?$top=20&$filter=DOB lt 1972-11-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

etc.

All fail with messages along the lines of :-

```
The query specified in the URI is not valid. The binary operator LessThan is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]'.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try the URL `http://localhost:53205/OData/Person?$top=20&$filter=DOB+eq+datetime'1972-11-20'`

Comment: Gives "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'datetime'1972-11-20'' at '7' in 'DOB eq datetime'1972-11-20''". - tried a few other permutations, with and without quotes etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that while Microsoft has [partly](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/datetime-support/) added DateTime support ([see comments](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/datetime-support/#comment-1883457274)), OData V4 doesn’t include DateTime as primitive type. This means that your filter still needs to use DateTimeOffset.

While not ideal, casting the DateTime to a DateTimeOffset seems to solve the problem.

```
/OData/Person?$top=20&$filter=cast(DOB,'Edm.DateTimeOffset') eq 1972-11-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Hope it helps. FYI: This issue is being tracked at https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/206 and will be fixed on the next Web API release (5.5) which is targeting March 30th, 2015.

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs because Odata doesn't support `DateTime` type but now Web API OData v4 supports it in release 5.5. Don't forget setting SetTimeZoneInfo:

```
config.SetTimeZoneInfo(TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

By default the timezone of the dateTime property would be considered as local timezone.

More info: [`ASP.NET Web API for OData V4 Docs DateTime support`](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/datetime-support/)