# how to properly use OData v4 DataTimeOffset with query fileters?

Tags: odata

I have an OData v4 WebAPI 2 end point:

```
http://windows-10:8888/Incident
```

This end-point needs to support filtering on the DateTime field:

```
http://windows-10:8888/Incident?$filter=REPORTEDDATE gt DateTimeOffset'2016-05-10%2016:01:53.000'
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
     "The query specified in the URI is not valid. 
    Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'DateTimeOffset'2016-05-10 16:01:53.000'' 
at '16' in 'REPORTEDDATE gt DateTimeOffset'2016-05-10 16:01:53.000''."
```

What is the proper technique to get such DateTime filtering accomplished with OData v4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per specification, http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html section 5.1.1.6.1 example:

http://localhost:23890/People?$expand=Trips($filter=StartsAt%20eq%202014-01-01T01:00:00-08:00) or http://localhost:23890/People?$expand=Trips($filter=StartsAt%20eq%202014-01-01T01:00:00.000-08:00) or http://localhost:23890/People?$expand=Trips($filter=StartsAt%20eq%202014-01-01T01:00:00Z)

I have validate Web APi OData or REStier, this works well.

Answer (score 1):

Found the correct syntax here:  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586797/the-binary-operator-lessthan-is-not-defined-for-the-types-system-nullable1sys`

In my case the syntax is:

```
http://windows-10:8888/Incident?$filter=cast(REPORTEDDATE,%27Edm.DateTimeOffset%27)%20gt%20%202016-05-10T22:38:00.000Z
```